# Getting a Crystal Report Viewer error on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, vb6, crystal-reports-xi

We've got an old VB6 app which uses Crystal Reports XI Release 2 to run reports against  a SQL Server 2005 database.  This has worked well over the years.  Also, for the last upteen years we've used Windows XP.  Well, we're beginning to migrate to Windows 7.  Well, now one of the users on Windows 7 cannot run the report.  It gives him an error of “Logon failed. Details: [Database Vendor Code: 6]”.  All of the Crystal Reports used in this application use an system ODBC connection.  I've verified, twice, that the system DNS properly authenticates against the SQL Server database.  However, when the user attempts to run any of the reports in the VB6 app, they all give that same error.  The weird thing is we've got another old VB6 app, which also uses Crystal Reports, and that app's reports work fine.  But that app runs against a local Microsoft Access database, not against SQL Server.

So the question is, are there any known issues involving SQL Server, Crystal Reports XI Release 2 and Windows 7?

Something else we just noticed.  On the 2 user machines that are exhibiting this problem, both are 64-bit Windows 7 machines.  So, could it instead be an issue of a 64-bit version of Windows, SQL Server and Crystal Reports XI Release 2?

Comment: Did you configure the odbc connection from administrative tools or by using version 'Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe'?  Version in SysWOW64 directory should be used for System DSN.

Comment: No, I did not.  I didn't even know about that.  OK, I'll do that as soon as I can get to the users' machines.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report 11.5 does run on 64 bit windows. Minimum req.ment is CR11 R2 SP6 to run on 64 bit.

Comment: Could you please add more details about your solution?